# Route [index.sign] not defined. Actually I want to localhost/index/sign in the URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have written the following route

```
Route::get('index/sign', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

Also When I want to click the sign-in a-tag button
**here a tag code.**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('index.sign') }}">Sign-In</a>
```

Then I want to open the page **sign-in** page according to URL *http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/sign*

Comment: Hi, Mubashir, can you maybe show the code you're using for the button. That way we can help you better

Comment: <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('index.sign') }}">Sign-In</a>
    </li>

Comment: Your route's name is `login`, not `index.sign`.

Comment: where it is written route name is login?

Comment: `->name('login');`

Comment: @Mubashir In your code. `index.sign` doesn't appear anywhere in your code. `index/sign` is the URL, not the route's name. `login` is the name, as set by `->name('login')`. When in doubt, do `php artisan route:list` to check.

Comment: Thanks, I hope got helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You route name is `'login'`

You may call `{{ route('login') }}`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want the A tag to redirect to your route.

You can do it like this:

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Sign-In</a>
```

In the A tag you want to use `route('login')` because that is the name you gave the route